# Create EigenSolver from MatrixWrapper

Tags: eigen3

How to construct an `EigenSolver` from a `MaxtrixWrapper`?

test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3CEigen/Eigen%3E%0Ausing+namespace+Eigen%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+D%3E%0Avoid+f(const+Eigen::DenseBase%3CD%3E%26+a)+%7B%0A++++const+Eigen::MatrixWrapper%3Cconst+D%3E+a2(a.derived())%3B%0A++++Eigen::EigenSolver%3Ctypename+Eigen::MatrixWrapper%3Cconst+D%3E%3E+%0A++++es(a2)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09ArrayXXf+a(3,+3)%3B%0A%09a+%3D+1.0f%3B%0A%09f(a)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.867242733699925,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:47.132757266300075,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename D>
void f(const Eigen::DenseBase<D>& a) {
    const Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const D> a2(a.derived());
    Eigen::EigenSolver<typename Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const D>> 
    es(a2);
}

int main() {
    ArrayXXf a(3, 3);
    a = 1.0f;
    f(a);
}
```

1st Error:

```
<...>/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h:71:10: error: 
‘Options’ is not a member of 
‘Eigen::EigenSolver<
    Eigen::MatrixWrapper<
        const Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1> 
    > 
 >::MatrixType {
 aka Eigen::MatrixWrapper<const Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1> >}’
     enum {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The solvers all want a plain `Matrix<...>` (or a `Ref<Matrix<...> >`) as template parameter. You can get the correct `Matrix` type using:

```
template<typename D>
void f(const Eigen::DenseBase<D>& a) {
    Eigen::EigenSolver<typename D::PlainMatrix> es(a.derived().matrix());
}
```

The `.derived().matrix()` is actually optional here, since `ArrayXXf` gets converted to `MatrixXf` implicitly. (godbolt times out on this -- the EigenSolver is quite heavy for the compiler).